# Skybox Cubemap not showing correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, skybox

I am trying to make a skybox with cube mapping using 6 textures. Out of all the cube map textures that I have used only 1 set of 6 textures works fine. I am not sure what is causing the problem.

This is how I am doing it:

**-Creating the CubeMap texture ID**

```
glGenTextures(1, &m_texHandle);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, m_texHandle);

for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    //create image/pixel buffer
    TextureLoader tex = TextureLoader(fileNames[i].c_str(), extension);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB,  tex.GetWidth(), tex.GetHeight(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex.GetBuffer());

}

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
```

**-Initialize and Rendering code**

```
void MeshData::InitializeSkyBox()
{

    GLfloat skyboxVertices[] = 
    {
        // Positions          
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

         1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,

        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f
    };

    m_indicieCount = 36;

    // Allocate an OpenGL vertex array object.
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vertexArrayID);

    // Bind the vertex array object to store all the buffers and vertex attributes we create here.
    glBindVertexArray(m_vertexArrayID);

    // Generate an ID for the vertex buffer.
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_vertexBufferID);

    // Bind the vertex buffer and load the vertex position data into the vertex buffer.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indicieCount * 3 * sizeof(float), &skyboxVertices[0], GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    // Enable the two vertex array attributes.
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  // Vertex position.

    // Specify the location and format of the position portion of the vertex buffer.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBufferID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
}

void MeshData::Render()
{
    //set cubemap texture for shader
    m_shader->SetShaderSampler("shaderTexture", 0, TextureManager::GetInstance()->GetTexture("skyBox"));

    glBindVertexArray(m_vertexArrayID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBufferID);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_indicieCount);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

**The SetShaderSampler function:**

```
bool Shader::SetShaderSampler(const char* name, int slot, TextureLoader* texture)
{
    if(texture == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Shader::SetShaderSampler setting a null texture" << endl;
        return true;
    }

    int loc = glGetUniformLocation(m_shaderProgram, name);
    if(loc >= 0)
    {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + slot);

        GLenum type = (texture->GetTextureType() == TextureLoader::CUBE_MAP_TGA) ? GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP : GL_TEXTURE_2D;

        glBindTexture(type, texture->GetHandle());

        glUniform1i(loc, slot);
    }

    return true;
}
```

**-Shader code**

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: cubeMap.vs
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#version 400


/////////////////////
// INPUT VARIABLES //
/////////////////////
layout(location = 0)in vec3 inputPosition;

//////////////////////
// OUTPUT VARIABLES //
//////////////////////
out vec3 texCoord;

///////////////////////
// UNIFORM VARIABLES //
///////////////////////
uniform mat4 worldMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Vertex Shader
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void main(void)
{
    // Calculate the position of the vertex against the view, and projection matrices.
    mat4 mv = projectionMatrix * mat4(mat3(viewMatrix));
    gl_Position = mv * vec4(inputPosition, 1.0);
    texCoord = inputPosition;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: cubeMap.ps
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#version 400


/////////////////////
// INPUT VARIABLES //
/////////////////////
in vec3 texCoord;


//////////////////////
// OUTPUT VARIABLES //
//////////////////////
out vec4 outputColor;


///////////////////////
// UNIFORM VARIABLES //
///////////////////////
uniform samplerCube shaderTexture;


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Pixel Shader
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void main(void)
{
    outputColor = texture(shaderTexture, texCoord);
}
```

**-Results I get**

This is the only set of cube map textures that works for me
[image]

Now here is where the issue comes in. I have tried a lot of different sets of textures and either it displays nothing or I get the issue below.

This is the original skybox cube map set of 6 textures
[image]

But when I play the game, it displays lines like this one
[image]

So any insights as to why this is happening? I believe that I am doing something wrong since out of most of the textures I have tried only one works.

Comment: Have you checked if the texture gets loaded correctly? Does it have the same size as the working one?

Comment: Wow, that's a really nice little [Trinitron CRT](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSxM8rYaPC4R3-gERdLleF2-BTPhJpdlTfBCsCOIk0kN0Oevv0M) shader effect you have created ;) I know this doesn't help you, but it had to be said. That aside, **... GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE ...** raises red flags for me. If your texture does not have power-of-two dimensions, RGB source data often creates alignment issues and other nasty things.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Alright I noticed that the textures had an alpha channel. I removed the alpha channel but now the cubemap texture looks different. The lines are gone now but the space textures have different colors now. Instead of the red "clouds", they are blue now and the planet is now yellow instead of blue. Looks pretty cool either way but its not correct. Thanks again for the replay though.

Comment: @Jose: Can you post the updated screenshot and the changes you made to code?

Comment: @Jose That's probably a color channel ordering issue, i.e. it's not RGB but BGR.

Comment: @Banex Awesome! That works. Thanks for replying guys. Dumb mistake on my part but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dumb mistake on my part but the solution to my problem was that I had an alpha channel on the texture. Once I removed the alpha channel, it worked correctly!